# SQL 2008 R2 - Update Rows with Incremented # and Restart with a chenge in Document number

Tags: sql, sql-server, increment

I'm trying to write a sql script that will update a column with an incrementing number but reset the number in a change of the document #.  I would like it to increment by the count of 10 if possible.  Line No is the column that I'm trying to update.

```
Document # ---- Line No
10001             10
10001             20
10001             30
20001             10
20001             20
30001             10
30001             20
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
with dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line] as (
    select t.*, 
        10 * row_number() over (partition by [Document No_] order by [Item No_] asc) as val
  from [Staging_External Sales Line] t
 )
update dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line]
    set [Line no_] = val;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are inherently unordered.  So, there is no such thing as a first row, second row or whatever for a given document.  You need to store that information in a column, such as an id or creation date.

The following query does the calculation:

```
select Document,
       10 * row_number() over (partition by Document order by (select NULL)) as val
from t;
```

You should replace the `(select NULL)` with the column that really has the ordering.

To do an update, you can use a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
          select Document,
                 10 * row_number() over (partition by Document order by (select NULL)) as val
          from t
         )
update toupdate
    set line_num = val;
```

EDIT:

It is better to edit your original question instead of embedding SQL in a comment.

Onw problem is that you cannot use multi-part naming conventions for aliases (I use `t` rather broadly, probably too broadly).  The second is that you don't want a nested select in the `order by` clause.  Here are revised versions of your questions.

```
select [Document No_],
       10 * row_number() over (partition by [Document No_] order by [Sort Order]) as val
from dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line] t;
```

And:

```
with toupdate as (
  select t.*,
         10 * row_number() over (partition by [Document No_] order by [Sort Order]) as val
  from dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line] t
 )
update toupdate
    set [Line no_] = val;
```

Comment: Gordon - Thanks for the quick response.  Here is the code I modified with the real column/table name.  I'm getting an error "Incorrect syntax near '.'. message when running.

Comment: select [Document No_], 10 * row_number() over (partition by [Sort Order] order by (select [Document No_])) as val
 from dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line]; with dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line] as
   (select [Document No_], 10 * row_number() over (partition by [Document No_] 
      order by (select [Sort Order])) as val from dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line])
   update dbo.[Staging_External Sales Line] set [Line no_] = val;

Comment: Gordon - The first section of code is doing exactly what I need.  Thank you!

Comment: NOW my issue is the 2nd set of code is error out saying that there is "Incorrect syntax near '.'.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . Yes, `[Line no_]` wasn't included in the CTE.

Comment: Gordon - Same error.  How do I paste my code up to the site for you to see?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . Go up to the question.  You should see an "edit" option, just below the tags.  Go to the end of the question and add "EDIT" (or something) so reader know you are making the modification.  Then paste the code in.  If you highlight the code and click on the curly-braces, then it will be formatted as code (or you can manually add four spaces to the beginning of each line).